# Join statement, but need to only get data based on WHERE table column is empty

Tags: sql, mysql

I have this query statement and want to only get records that has a certain column empty (`volunteers_2009.venue_id`)

Table is `volunteers_2009`, column I am looking to see if it is empty: `venue_id`

Here is the current query:

```
SELECT volunteers_2009.id, volunteers_2009.comments, 
   volunteers_2009.choice1, volunteers_2009.choice2, volunteers_2009.choice3, 
   volunteers_2009.lname, volunteers_2009.fname, volunteers_2009.venue_id, 
   venues.venue_name 
FROM volunteers_2009 AS volunteers_2009 
LEFT OUTER JOIN venues ON (volunteers_2009.venue_id = venues.id) 
ORDER by $order $sort
```

I am trying to do this:

```
SELECT volunteers_2009.id, volunteers_2009.comments, 
   volunteers_2009.choice1, volunteers_2009.choice2, volunteers_2009.choice3, 
   volunteers_2009.lname, volunteers_2009.fname, volunteers_2009.venue_id, 
   venues.venue_name 
FROM volunteers_2009 AS volunteers_2009 
LEFT OUTER JOIN venues ON (volunteers_2009.venue_id = venues.id) 
ORDER by $order $sort 
WHERE volunteers_2009.venue_id == ''
```

How would I only list records that have an empty column (`venue_id`) within the table (`volunteers_2009`)?

Comment: When you say empty do you mean empty string or NULL? They are two different things

Comment: If you're really querying on an empty string then the query you posted should work. Could you provide more details on what exactly is not working with the current query.

Comment: Assuming that venues.id is a primary key, you won't be able to join on it when volunteers_2009.venue_id is null.  Are you sure you don't want to select records where venues.venue_name is null -- i.e., no matching venue for the volunteer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WHERE clause is out of order in your 2nd query.  It must go before the ORDER BY clause.

Also, I don't imagine you have any venues with an empty id.  Perhaps what you really want is this:

```
SELECT volunteers_2009.id, volunteers_2009.comments, 
    volunteers_2009.choice1, volunteers_2009.choice2, volunteers_2009.choice3, 
    volunteers_2009.lname, volunteers_2009.fname, volunteers_2009.venue_id, 
    venues.venue_name 
FROM volunteers_2009 
LEFT JOIN venues ON venue_id = venues.id
WHERE venues.id IS NULL
ORDER BY $order $sort
```

That will bring back only volunteers_2009 records that don't match any venues.

Or this:

```
SELECT volunteers_2009.id, volunteers_2009.comments, 
    volunteers_2009.choice1, volunteers_2009.choice2, volunteers_2009.choice3, 
    volunteers_2009.lname, volunteers_2009.fname, volunteers_2009.venue_id, 
    venues.venue_name 
FROM venues
LEFT JOIN volunteers_2009 ON volunteers_2009.venue_id = venues.id
WHERE volunteers_2009.venue_id IS NULL
ORDER BY $order $sort
```

to find venues with no volunteers.

Answer (score 4):

By empty do you mean null? If the `venue_id` field can contain nulls then you can compare using the `is` operator like this:

```
WHERE volunteers_2009.venue_id is null
```

Comment: Yes, NULL, but it does not display NULL when I display the table in CocoaMySQL